# Conditional subsetting by POSIXct interval and another field containing interval

Tags: r, subset, apply, posixct

Given a dataset Dat where I have species (SP), Area (AR), and Time (TM) (in POSIXct).
I want to subset the data for individuals that were present with Species A, within a half hour prior and after it was recorded, and within the same area, including two adjacent areas (+ and - 1). For example, if species A was present at 1:00 on area 4, I wish to subset all species present from 12:30 to 1:30 in the same day in areas 3,4 and 5. As an example:

```
SP         TM      AR
B  1-jan-03 07:22  1
F  1-jan-03 09:22  4
A  1-jan-03 09:22  1
C  1-jan-03 08:17  3
D  1-jan-03 09:20  1
E  1-jan-03 06:55  4
D  1-jan-03 09:03  1
E  1-jan-03 09:12  2
F  1-jan-03 09:45  1
B  3-jan-03 09:15  1
A  3-jan-03 10:30  5
F  3-jan-03 07:30  5
F  3-jan-03 10:20  6
D  3-jan-03 10:05  4
```

The desired result for this dummy table would be:

```
SP         TM      AR
A  1-jan-03 09:22  1
D  1-jan-03 09:20  1
D  1-jan-03 09:03  1
E  1-jan-03 09:12  2
F  1-jan-03 09:45  1
A  3-jan-03 10:30  5
F  3-jan-03 10:20  6
D  3-jan-03 10:05  4
```

Note: Species A appears repeatedly throughout the dataset in any given area ranging from 1-81 ant any given time.
On a previous set of post, I broke this question in two, so I could learn how to integrate the codes, but my specifications for the problem were flawed. Many thanks to the users *Thelatemail* and *Jason* who provided helpful answers. [Subsetting based on co-occurrence within a time window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689748/subsetting-based-on-co-occurrence-within-a-time-window/18690052?noredirect=1#18690052)
[Subsetting neighboring fileds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706182/subsetting-neighboring-fileds/18706352?noredirect=1#18706352)
The feedback was:

```
with(dat,dat[
(
SP=="A" |
Area %in% c(Area[SP=='A']-1, Area[SP=='A'], Area[SP=='A']+1)
) & 
apply(
sapply(Time[SP=="A"],
function(x) abs(difftime(Time,x,units="mins"))<=30 ),1,any
) 
,]
)
```

Which worked partially, however, it only subsets within the time window, not by area. I think it is caused by issues with POSIXct and using the subset commands, since different times are included in a time window. Would another apply function be necessary for separating that area interval? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It would be great if you could insert links to your previous questions. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the line `SP=='A' |` and you should have what you need.  See if you can say, in words, what each line is doing and follow the logic in the subsetting.  It will be a good exercise and will help with your understanding of R (see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706182/subsetting-neighboring-fieds/18706352?noredirect=1#18706352))

Comment: You could rewrite `c(Area[SP=='A']-1, Area[SP=='A'], Area[SP=='A']+1)` as `Area[SP=='A'] + c(-1, 0, 1)` (but I don't think `%in%` works the way you expect). And naming intermediate results would make your code much easier to understand

Comment: @Justin, do you get `F 2003-01-01 09:22:00  4` included when you run your code? It is close in space, but at the wrong time (A is in Area 5, but on the 3rd), or vice versa: close in time, but on the wrong site (A is seen same time, but is then in Area 1). Could it be the `any` in `apply` that allows for this, i.e. 'any' true time is resulting in an aggregated TRUE, regardless of space for the single TRUE? I apologize in advance if I have messed things up.

Comment: I haven't actually run any of the code...

Comment: @Justin :) I was trying soooooo desperate to create a solution myself, got extreeeemely frustrated. And gave up. So I started to go through your nice answer instead to get some ideas and learn and happened to stumble over this one row...Sorry.

Comment: I can provide a larger chunk of the original dataset:

Comment: If the test data includes the properties that you wish a code should deal with, there is no need for more. I tend to think that the shorter the better. But thanks for the offer! And thanks for providing _both_ a nice little test data set _and_ a desired output, and a clearly formulated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution very much inspired by [@thelatemail's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689748/subsetting-based-on-co-occurrence-within-a-time-window) and [@Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706182/subsetting-neighboring-fileds/18706352?noredirect=1#18706352) previous, nice answers, but this accounts for time in the boolean expression for space (see my comments to this question).

Using `sapply`, we 'loop' over each time of registration of Species A (`time[SP == "A"]`), and create a boolean matrix `mm` with one column per registration of A. Each row represents a test for space and time for each registration against a given registration of A.

```
mm <- with(dat,
           sapply(time[SP == "A"], function(x)
             abs(AR - AR[SP == "A" & time == x]) <= 1 &
                    abs(difftime(time, x, units = "mins")) <= 30))

# select rows from data where at least one column in mm is TRUE    
dat[rowSums(mm) > 0, ]

# SP                time AR
# 3   A 2003-01-01 09:22:00  1
# 5   D 2003-01-01 09:20:00  1
# 7   D 2003-01-01 09:03:00  1
# 8   E 2003-01-01 09:12:00  2
# 9   F 2003-01-01 09:45:00  1
# 11  A 2003-01-03 10:30:00  5
# 13  F 2003-01-03 10:20:00  6
# 14  D 2003-01-03 10:05:00  4
```

Comment: Great edit, I noticed you cleaned up the code on the AR conditionals. I was trying the same thing yesterday.  Very well made.

Comment: interestingly, after running the code with the edit, it does not give a warning message, which I believe is related to areas that have no neighbors (for example 1, which would only include 2, but not zero).

Comment: @Karl, glad to hear that it worked. Sorry for not notifying you about the edit. I was a bit stressed today...